# Very basic React toDo-List

Tags: react.js, to-do-list

After learning a bit React in the last weeks I've decided to make a toDo-list.

I've got the basic-functionalities (create, update, delete entries) finished.

I'm going to enhance the app with a feature for to define priorities. Moreover should it be possible to change the order of entries.

For the final-syling I'm going to use Foundation.

But before going on I would appreciate to read the opinion of more experienced React-developer.

So therefore: Any hints and recommendations concerning flaws and possible improvements welcomed.

```js
var Issue = React.createClass({
  triggerUpdate: function(e) {        // Call func-ref passed by the parent 
    this.props.update(this.props.id); //  Assign own id to it.
  },
  triggerDelete: function(e) {
    this.props.delete(this.props.id);
  },
  render: function() {
    var issueStyle = {
      marginBottom: '20px'
    };

    var textStyle = {
      marginBottom: '10px',
      padding: '5px 10px',
      width: '100%'
    }

    return (
      <div className="issue" style={ issueStyle } >
        <div onChange={ this.triggerUpdate } style={ textStyle } 
          ref="inputText" type="text" className="issue-text"
          maxLength="200" >{ this.props.issueText }
        </div>
        <div className="button-bar">
          <button onClick={ this.triggerUpdate } >Edit</button>
          <button onClick={ this.triggerDelete } >Delete</button></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Gui = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      issueText: '', // Holds current content-textbox.
      issues: [],    // The issues already created.
      activeId: -1
    }
  },
  getIndexOfIssue: function(id) {
    var ret;

    this.state.issues.forEach(function(issue, i) {
      if (+issue.id === +id) {
        ret = i;
      }
    });

    return ret;
  },
  toggleUpdateMode: function(id) { // Func. used to set & remove update-mode.
    if (typeof id === 'number' && id > -1) { // Without parameter => Remove mode.
      this.setState({
        issueText: 
        this.state.issues[this.getIndexOfIssue(id)].text
      }); 
    } else {
      this.setState({
        issueText: ''
      });
    }

    this.setState({
      activeId: id >= 0 ? id : -1
    });

    this.refs.write.classList.toggle('hidden'); 
    this.refs.writeChanges.classList.toggle('hidden');  
  },
  addIssue: function() {    
    this.state.issues.push(
      { id: this.state.issues.length,
       text: this.state.issueText
      } );

    this.setState({
      issueText: ''
    });
  },
  writeChanges: function() {
    this.state.issues[this.state.activeId].text =
      this.state.issueText;
    this.forceUpdate();
    this.toggleUpdateMode();
  },
  setIssueText: function (e) {
    let textBoxContent = e.target.value;
    var currentButton =
        document.querySelector('.main-nav button:not(.hidden)');

    this.setState({
      issueText: textBoxContent
    });

    textBoxContent.length > 2
      ? currentButton.classList.remove('disabled')
    : currentButton.classList.add('disabled');
  },
  delete: function(id) {
    this.state.issues.splice(id, 1);
    this.forceUpdate();
  },
  render: function () {
    var that = this;
    var currentIssues = this.state.issues.map(function(issue, i) {
      return (
        <Issue key={ i } id={ i } issueText={ issue.text }
          delete={ that.delete } update={ that.toggleUpdateMode } >
        </Issue>
      );
    }); 
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="main-nav">
          <div>
            <label  htmlFor="issueText">Issue</label>
            <input maxLength="200" size="150"
              type="text" id="issueText"
              ref="issueText" onChange={ this.setIssueText }
              value={ this.state.issueText } />
          </div>
          <div className="button-bar">
            <button onClick={ this.addIssue } className="disabled write-trigger"
              ref="write">Write</button>
            <button onClick={ this.writeChanges } ref="writeChanges"
              className="hidden write-trigger">
              Write changes
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>{ currentIssues }</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Gui />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #dedede;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.wrap {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.button-bar {
  margin: 10px 20px 20px;
}

.button-bar button {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.issue-text {
  background-color: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 6px;  
}

label {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 120px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}

input:hover, button:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.main-nav div:first-child {
  position: relative;
}

.main-nav div:first-child:hover:before {
  content: 'Issue needs at least 3 characters';
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: #787878;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.main-nav div:first-child:hover:after {
  content: '';
  border-top: 16px solid #787878;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  left: 25%;
  top: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```